# Codeigniter Chat

Tags: php, codeigniter, chat

I am looking codeigniter chat script.

I expect like http://anantgarg.com/chat/sampleb.php.

Have anyone know any script for codeigniter chat?

Answer (score 4):

You can find a detailed set of video tutorials on building a chat application on codeigntier - [Codeigniter Tutorial – Creating A Web Chat App using JQuery AJAX](http://www.simplycodeigniter.com/2011/06/codeigniter-tutorial-creating-a-web-chat-app-using-jquery-ajax-part-1/)

There is also [this](http://www.llbbl.com/2007/11/01/jquery-and-codeigniter-chat/) and [this](http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/) resources.

Answer (score 3):

To do this efficiently you should use an efficient transport like for example:

- [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets)
- [flash-socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLSocket)
- [long-polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)
- [http-streaming](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming#Solution)

but not [polling(periodic refresh)](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Periodic_Refresh#Solution), because this has scaling problems written all over it.

Luckily you can use [pusher](http://pusher.com/) to achieve this. Pusher does have a free price plan which should get you started.

> Our free Sandbox plan includes up to 20 connections and 100,000
>   messages per day. Simply upgrade to a paid plan when you're ready.

Long before you hit that generous quota your server would have collapsed under the load if you used polling(periodic refresh). Furthermore you will probably get notice(maybe site taken down) from your shared hosting provider if you are doing periodic refresh. I know this because in the past I had such chat system using periodic refresh on a small forum and I got a notice because the server was under tremendous load.

Thanks to a developer named Squeeks you can get started with Pusher without any effort because he created a nice little library called [Pusher-php](https://github.com/squeeks/Pusher-PHP) which uses the [REST protocol](http://pusher.com/docs/rest_api) to communicate with pusher API. You don't need to worry about the details